# How to randomly select 50 files and copy them to different folder/directory (MacOS)?

Tags: macos, shell, terminal, bioinformatics

I am trying to randomly select 50 files (.nexus files) from a directory and copy them into a separate target directory.

I found the following script on a question page regarding a similar topic with 8 items to be randomly selected:

shuf -zn8 -e *.jpg | xargs -0 cp -vt target/

shuf shuffles the list of *.jpg files in the current directory.
-z is to zero-terminate each line, so that files with special characters are treated correctly.
-n8 exits shuf after 8 files.
xargs -0 reads the input delimited by a null character (from shuf -z) and runs cp.
-v is to print every copy verbosely.
-t is to specify the target directory.

When entering this in the terminal, I figured out that -t is not a valid command for MacOS. However, after removing it, I still cannot seem to get the script to work. The output from entering the script below is:

usage: cp [-R [-H | -L | -P]] [-fi | -n] [-apvXc] source_file target_file
       cp [-R [-H | -L | -P]] [-fi | -n] [-apvXc] source_file ... target_directory

The code I've been using is below. I use gshuf instead of shuf and the long file path is my target directory for the files to be copied to.

I am fairly new to coding, etc. so any suggestions would be appreciated! Thanks!

gshuf -zn50 -e *.nexus | xargs -0 cp -v ~/Users/brandon/Dropbox/Macbook/CH2_macrops_UCE_project/taxon-sets/all_outgroups3/macrops_randomly_sampled_50_A

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try another parameter of `xargs`:

```
shuf -zn8 -e *.jpg | xargs -0 -I{} cp -v {} target/
```

`-I` allows you to specify a string that will be substituted my the actual input, so that `xargs` would be equivalent to:

```
cp -v <file1> <file2> ... <fileN> target/
```

In your particular case:

```
gshuf -zn50 -e *.nexus | xargs -0 -I{} cp -v {} ~/Users/brandon/Dropbox/Macbook/CH2_macrops_UCE_project/taxon-sets/all_outgroups3/macrops_randomly_sampled_50_A
```

Answer (score 6):

as you say you are fairly new to this maybe stick to something simple

```
cp $(ls | sort -R | head -50) targetdir/
```

`cp` copies
`ls` lists your current dir (note it only makes columns when it outputs to the screen)
`sort` orders the list it gets from `ls` but the `-R` tells it to make a random order
`head` takes the top of the randomized list from `sort` `-50` tell how many

the `$()`  returns the result of the execution of what is in the parens

and of course the `|`  pipes text between commands from left (output)  to right  (input)